# Price fields and cents separator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have several price fields. In the `model` they are of type `float` and when I want to display them, I use the `number_to_currency` method provided by `NumberHelper`  and this works fine. However, the input in the form is a problem. Here in The Netherlands, the divider for decimal amounts is a comma, but some people use a dot. Currently, only a decimal amount with a dot gets saved properly. When a decimal is used, only the whole amount gets saved.

So I probably need a `before_save sanitizer` which replaces a comma with a dot. But I need this for several models. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As the api documentation [describes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) the method `number_to_currency` has the option `:separator` you may use.

```
number_to_currency("1234567890,50", unit: "&pound;", separator: ",", delimiter: "")
```

Maybe you can set the locale and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have that problem in Germany, too.

I've been using the [**delocalize**](https://github.com/clemens/delocalize) gem to perform the "reverse localization", although it still has some problems with Rails 4. (It works, though)

PS: Don't use floating point types for representing currency, you'll get rounding problems. Use `BigDecimal` instead.